# Why is my addrinfo struct full of garbage after calling getaddrinfo()?

Tags: c++, sockets

there's a mistake somewhere in the following code, but I couldn't figure it out so far.

```
    struct addrinfo hints, *addrinfo;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_protocol = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;

    if (int result{ getaddrinfo("192.168.178.68", "5642", &hints, &addrinfo) }; result != 0) {
        throw "Please create an exception here";
    }

    auto debug = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in*> (addrinfo);
    std::cout << inet_ntoa(debug->sin_addr) << std::endl << debug->sin_family << std::endl
        << debug->sin_port << std::endl;
```

The last line of this prints out garbage data, I expected it to print out the values I passed in the getaddrinfo() call. I've managed to "manually" set up a sockaddr_in struct which behaves correctly, but I'd still like to figure out why this one doesn't work. I assume it has to do with the cast.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You're casting a pointer to a `struct addrinfo` to a pointer to a `struct sockaddr_in`... the two types are not compatible. Of course you're not going to get anything meaningful.

Comment: There must be several tens of thousands of examples on how to use `getaddrinfo`, all over the Internet. None of them (at least none of the working examples) should do a cast like you do. Where did you find code like that? Who told you to cast the `addrinfo` pointer into a `sockaddr_in` pointer?

Comment: In `hints.ai_protocol = AF_UNSPEC;`, `AF_UNSPEC` is not a protocol, it should only be used in the `hints.ai_family` field. You have to use a valid protocol for `hints.ai_protocol`, which for a `SOCK_DGRAM` socket would be `IPPROTO_UDP` for example. `AF_UNSPEC` is defined as 0, which is the same value as `IPPROTO_IP`, which is not a valid protocol for `SOCK_DGRAM`. Fortunately, setting `hints.ai_protocol = 0` tells `getaddrinfo()` to ignore `hints.ai_protocol` and return addresses for *any* protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `ai_addr` and `ai_addrlen` fields of the `addrinfo` structure, not try to treat the `addrinfo` itself like a completely different type. Something like:

```
char host[NI_MAXHOST], port[NI_MAXSERV];
int err;
if ((err = getnameinfo(addrinfo->ai_addr, addrinfo->ai_addrlen,
                       host, sizeof host, port, sizeof port,
                       NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICPORT)) == 0) {
  std::cout << host << '\n' << addrinfo->ai_family << '\n'
            << port << '\n';
} else {
  std::cerr << "Error: " << gai_strerror(err) << '\n';
}
```

---

This line is also a problem:

```
hints.ai_protocol = AF_UNSPEC;
```

From [the manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html):

> `ai_protocol` This field specifies the protocol for the returned socket addresses.  Specifying 0 in this field indicates that socket addresses with any protocol can be returned by `getaddrinfo()`.

`AF_UNSPEC` should only be used with the `ai_family` field when you don't want to return only IPv4 or IPv6 addresses, but possibly both.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While I could succesfully retrieve the address that I passed to getaddrinfo() this way, I am unable to use addrinfo->ai_addr in a sendto() call, which was my original intent. I reckon I made another misassumption here? sendto(fd, msg_buf, strlen(msg_buf), 0, res->ai_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

Comment: @relativity_face The address might not be `sizeof(struct sockaddr)` bytes long. Use the provided address length field.

Comment: This was not the problem unfortunately. I also tried hardcoding *buf and len into the call to check whether something with those parameters is wrong, but sendto() returns 0. That really confuses me, since 0 indicates that no error occured, right?                                                                       
      int test = sendto(fd, "Hey", 3, 0, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);

Comment: @relativity_face Does `sendto` return with a failure (e.g. `-1`)? Then have you checked `errno` to see *what* the failure was? And remember that `getaddrinfo` returns a *list* of addresses, have you tried iterating over that list? Oh, and you do use the info returned by `getaddrinfo` before you call `freeaddrinfo`? And please, post another question with this new problem, not forgetting to include a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: @relativity_face the `sockaddr`(s) returned by `getaddrinfo()` can be used with ANY function that takes a `sockaddr*` as input, which includes `sendto()`. If you are getting an error from a function, it is because you are calling the function incorrectly. But `sendto()` returning 0 is not an error condition, returning -1 is. On the other hand, `sendto()` should NEVER return 0 when `len > 0` as it is in your example. The datagram is either sent in full, or not at all, there are no partial sends in UDP.

Comment: @relativity_face Updated my answer with another issue in your code. If that doesn't help, then, yeah, another question with more detail and code is a good idea.

Comment: Following your advices, I got all my mistakes sorted out and everything works fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are type-casting the `addrinfo` itself to a `sockaddr_in`, which is wrong.  An `addrinfo` is not itself a `sockaddr_in`, but it can *point* to a `sockaddr_in`.  `getaddrinfo()` returns a linked list of 1 or more `addrinfo` structs, each one pointing to an appropriate `sockaddr_...` struct in its `ai_addr` field. You need to iterate that list, using each of those structs as needed.

Also, you are using `AF_UNSPEC` with the `hints.ai_protocol` field, but it is not a protocol value, it should only be used with the `hints.ai_family` field.  A valid `ai_protocol` value for a `SOCK_DGRAM` socket would be `IPPROTO_UDP`, for instance.  It just happens that `AF_UNSPEC` has a value of 0, and setting `hints.ai_protocol` to 0 tells `getaddrinfo()` to return addresses for *any* protocol.

Try this instead:

```cpp
addrinfo hints, *addrs;

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;

int result = getaddrinfo("192.168.178.68", "5642", &hints, &addrs);
if (result != 0) {
    throw "Please create an exception here";
}

for(auto addr = addrs; addr != nullptr; addr = addr->ai_next)
{
    auto in4 = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in*>(addr->ai_addr);
    std::cout << in4->sin_family << std::endl
              << inet_ntoa(in4->sin_addr) << std::endl
              << ntohs(in4->sin_port) << std::endl;
}

freeaddrinfo(addrs);
```

That being said, if you set `hints.ai_family` to `AF_UNSPEC` then `getaddrinfo()` can return a list containing *EITHER* `sockaddr_in` *OR* `sockaddr_in6` structs, *OR BOTH*:

```cpp
addrinfo hints, *addrs;

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;

int result = getaddrinfo("192.168.178.68", "5642", &hints, &addrs);
if (result != 0) {
    throw "Please create an exception here";
}

char ipaddrbuf[46];
for(auto addr = addrs; addr != nullptr; addr = addr->ai_next)
{
    switch (addr->ai_family /* or: addr->ai_addr->sa_family */ )
    {
        case AF_INET:
        {
            auto in4 = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in*>(addr->ai_addr);
            std::cout << in4->sin_family << std::endl
                      << inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(in4->sin_addr), ipaddrbuf, sizeof(ipaddrbuf)) << std::endl
                      << ntohs(in4->sin_port) << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        case AF_INET6:
        {
            auto in6 = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in6*>(addr->ai_addr);
            std::cout << in6->sin6_family << std::endl
                      << inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(in6->sin6_addr), ipaddrbuf, sizeof(ipaddrbuf)) << std::endl
                      << ntohs(in6->sin6_port) << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}

freeaddrinfo(addrs);
```

Comment: You're confusing family and protocol. OP used a family of `AF_INET` so they'll only get ipv4 addresses. Of course, they shouldn't be using `AF_UNSPEC` for the protocol...

Comment: @Shawn Good catch, though that doesn't really invalidate my answer, it just means the `AF_INET6` case will never be reached. I have updated my answer, though.